# Do script addresses have a staking part? Is it possible to stake from smart contracts on Cardano?

Tags: wallet, smart-contract, script-addresses

I heard somewhere that staking from smart contracts may be possible on Cardano, and I wonder if that is because there is a staking part to script addresses on Cardano?

[CIP 19](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip19/#shelleyaddresses) discusses wallet addresses on Cardano, but it is not clear to me how or if this information relates to script addresses also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can, if you look in the CIP19, it has the header of `0001....`.

This address contains both the script has, as well as the stake key hash.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to add constraints for delegation into the Plutus script or tx?

Comment: So a smart contract lending platform or decentralized exchange could either delegate to its own chosen stakepools and then pass on the staking rewards to liquidity providers, OR the dapp could somehow create mangled addresses so liquidity providers get to choose who they want to delegate to while the funds are at the script address? The first option sounds easier to implement but the second gives more freedom, am I understanding this correctly?